# Turn off warnings coming from subprojects

Tags: xcode, xcode4, compiler-warnings

Can someone help me to turn off warnings in Xcode 4 that I'm getting from subprojects?

I have three subprojects, with a lot of warnings. The subprojects are provide by my customer's R&D studio. I would like to turn off the warnings there, to put all my efforts and attention on warnings in my own code.

[image: This the xcode warning counter now]

Is this possibile in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you're using Xcode 4.2 or later, you can use LLVM compiler setting `Inhibit All Warnings` in `Warning Polices` for every subproject you have:

[image]

Comment: In my case, the subproject is a git submodule. It's owned by 3rd party and is constantly updating, so I'd really like to avoid modifying any of its files. Is there any way to do this in the main-project level? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you create a private cocoapods repository for the 3rd party project you can include it with a pod file and turn off the warnings with the inhibit_all_warnings! option.

You can find more infos here http://cocoapods.org

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution only:

If your subprojects build libraries or bundles that do not have to recompile at every run, you can activate the "recent filer" (see figure, blue clock). Then, only warnings and errors from the last compiler run are displayed.

[image: recent filter]

Comment: I've been having this problem, and this solution doesn't work for me: the subproject warnings are still displayed and furthermore it makes navigating the project more confusing.

Comment: @VicSmith: I guess, your subprojects do not generat libraries or bundles; thus they may compiled every time. What you can do is to sort the issues "By File" and collapse your subprojects in the issue inspector. Then you get only one issue sign for each subproject.

Comment: Thank you @Matthias but this is not the solution i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the library isn't too big, You could disable warnings on a per-file basis using

```cpp
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwarning-flag"
```

Comment: One of the library is a 15 years old lib with 1000+ source code files :(. And i want disable warning only when i'm compiling the source from the app project. Not when their working on the lib

Comment: Sorry :) Are most errors of a specific kind of they're just general errors ? What about compiling them in a separate project as static libraries, and then including the libraries without the actual source ?

Comment: Because i need, as requirement from the customer, to have these libs as subprojects in xcode

Comment: OK, i get that, But just for the development time you could pre-compile these libraries, just to avoid having the warnings while working. When delivering your code to the client, remove your libraries, put back the source code as subprojects and deliver it to the client.

Comment: During the development process i need to share the project with the client. From that my original question: "There is a way to turn off warning in xcode from subprojects?". Any solution that remove the subprojects from the context is appreciate but is not the solution i'm looking for.