# Disable warnings coming from a specific folder

Tags: xcode, xcode4, compiler-warnings

I've set up an Xcode project where part of the code (a folder in this case) comes from a svn repository.

The folder is **constantly updated by an external partner** and it contains `.h` and `.m` files. In particular, these files are included in the project since set up as **Header Search Paths** and **Library Search Paths** within my Target.

Since, `.h` files contain a lot of warnings (I receive the **Showing first 200 warning only** message), Xcode does not allow me to show my code warnings.

Based on this scenario, how is it possible to prevent Xcode to show those warnings for that specific folder?

I followed few discussions within SO ([Selectively disable GCC warnings for only part of a translation unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965093/selectively-disable-gcc-warnings-for-only-part-of-a-translation-unit/3394305#3394305), [Turn off warnings coming from subprojects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841479/turn-off-warnings-coming-from-subprojects)) but I haven't found a solution yet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have that many warnings, maybe it is better to address the warnings directly (refactor) than indirectly (hide them).

Comment: @TReddy Thank you for your comment. What do you mean with refactor? Those files change frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I've found a solution I reply to my own question. Hope this can help other people.

A partial solution for the problem can be found here at [How to disable new Xcode 4.6 warning for whole project ? “… used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579197/how-to-disable-new-xcode-4-6-warning-for-whole-project-used-as-the-name-of). I upvoted!

Obviously, I'm waiting the vendor will fix the problem since this workaround disable such type of warnings for my own code. And I don't want such type of behavior.

Cheers.